# BotBuilder - FormFlow - How to fix mistakes?

Tags: artificial-intelligence, bots, botframework, formflow

working with Microsoft Bot Framework I'm facing with [FormFlow](http://docs.botframework.com/sdkreference/csharp/forms.html).
The process is almost clear except how to manage the case the user wrong to select an option then doing a step back and fix it without waiting all the process ends.
Finally is not clear how to use LUIS into FormFlow are there other resources then the official Sandwich example?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

By default, FormFlow supports several commands at each step, including `back`, which allows the user to return to previous question. You can use `help` at any time to see the list of possible commands.

You can have LUIS working together with FormBuilder by passing reference to LUIS entities upon starting the Dialog. More details [here](http://docs.botframework.com/sdkreference/csharp/forms.html#initialState).